# Export Csv Content Magento 2

Tags: magento2, csv, export

Is there any way to export the values of "Description" for Default Store View into a csv ? 
I run a export but it is showing only the Description content of the Default Scope . 
Im able to see the values in database by running
 `select * from catalog_product_entity_text where store_id = 1` . But i want them in a csv .

Comment: add line before fetch description `$_product->setData('store_id', 1);`

Comment: what does "I run a export" mean? Is it a custom module or a native feature?

Comment: @vitoriodachef for the default magento 2 product export